# General Solution of $y'' - \frac{2}{x}y' + \frac{2}{x^2}y = 0,\; y_1= x$ (reduction of order method)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

I was given the question

> Use the reduction of order method to find the general solution of the
>   equation below. One solution of the homogeneous equation is shown
>   alongside the equation   $$ y'' - \frac{2}{x}y' + \frac{2}{x^2}y = 0,\quad y_1= x $$

Please these were the steps I took:

$y = y_1\int{u} \ dx $

where $u = u(x)$

$y = x\int{u} \ dx$

$y' = xu + \int{u} \ dx$

$y'' = xu' + 2u $

substituting $y,y',y''$ into $ y'' - \frac{2}{x}y' + \frac{2}{x^2}y = 0 $

$xu' + 2u - \frac{2}{x}(xu + \int{u}\ dx) + \frac{2}{x^2}x\int{u}\ dx  $

$xu' + 2u -2u - \frac{2}{x}\int{u}\ dx +  \frac{2}{x}\int{u}\ dx  $

$xu' = 0  $

$x\ du = dx  $

$ du = \frac1x\ dx  $

$ u = \ln{x}  + c $

substituting 
$$ u = \ln{x}  + c $$ into 
$$y = y_1\int{u} \ dx $$

$ y = x \int{\ln{x} + c} $

$ y = x^2( \ln{x} - 1) + c_1x^2 + c_2x $

**But the general solution was**
$$ y = c_1x + c_2x^2 $$

**Please where did I go wrong or how do I get to the final solution of $ y = c_1x + c_2x^2 $**

Comment: You did a mistake in "$xu'=0\implies du=\dfrac1x dx$" it is wrong. From $xu'=0$ we have $u'=0$ or $u=c$

Comment: This is an Euler-Cauchy equation with characteristic polynomial $0=m(m-1)-2m+2=(m-1)(m-2)$ and thus basis solutions $x,x^2$ like in the reference solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a  mistake in solving $xu'=0$. This does not give you $xdu=dx$. The correct solution for this is $u=c$ a constant.